# htaccess rewrite to add .html if it exists otherwise leave the URL as is

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a situation where I need to do a  URL rewrite IF a file exists otherwise leave the URL as is.

Here's an example:

```
http://mydomain.com/section -> if http://mydomain.com/section exists go to -> http://mydomain.com/section.html
http://mydomain.com/section -> if http://mydomain.com/section.html DOES NOT exist go to -> http://mydomain.com/section
```

How can I do this with a rewritecond?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava, but it isn't quite doing what I need :( When I go to http://mydomain.com/section it loads http://mydomain.com/section/index.html which I only want it to do if http://mydomain.com/section.html DOESN'T exist, which in my case it does. Thanks again

Comment: But you wrote: **`http://mydomain.com/section -> exists? yes -> http://mydomain.com/section.html`** I am confused what exactly is the requirement now.

Comment: Sorry anubhava I clarified the question. And, when I say "go to" I mean change the URL